# for key in dictionary if key ==x:

Tags: python

I am wondering if there is a similar way to enforce an if clause in a for loop as it is in a list comprehension. So I am looking to have a similar structure to

```
[ expression for item in list if conditional ]
```

in a loop, so sth like

```
for item in list if conditional:
    expression
```

I know that I could just add the conditional in the next line, however I was wondering if that can be built in the for loop already

Comment: Sorry - what does this have to do with dictionaries?

Comment: Looking at the title of the question, why do you need to loop through dictionary if you are looking for a specific key?

Comment: Even though you *could* do it with a generator expression, I think having a separate `if` statement is by far the cleanest.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. was meant for any iterable, not dict specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a generator comprehension

```
for item in ( x for x in list if condition(x) ):
    pass
```

Which is quite messy, come to think of it. Use a separate if statement; it makes your code better structured, and you want your code better structured.

Comment: ok, if statement it is. thanks also for showing how it would be possible with a generator

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there's no nicer way for this than the following one:

```
for item in iterable:
    if not conditional:
        continue
    # whatever
```

You could create a generator though but usually that's kind of overkill:

```
iteritems = (item for item in iterable if conditional)
for item in iteritems:
    pass # whatever
```

Of course you can compact this even more:

```
for item in (item for item in iterable if conditional):
    pass # whatever
```

But I wouldn't really call this pretty anymore. Let's keep the good old `continue` in such a case.

Comment: thanks. Looks like I have to keep that line. Also, thanks for showing the generator. Wont use it to replace the classic loop, but I was not very familiar with it, so, I learned something new. Always good

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I'd go with @ThiefMaster's approach. If you're looking for an alternate approach (which sometimes I do, just depends on how concise the conditional is and how well it integrates with the actual "do" part), you can go the functional route and use filter()...

```
for item in filter(lambda x: conditional, iterable):
    pass #whatever
```